# How to create a loop that outputs the max value of a column in an m x n matrix?

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I am new to MATLAB and I am working on a project. I am trying to program a Gaussian elimination algorithm with the use of pivoting through LU factorization (PA = LU).

In this project I am trying to take the largest value in the first column of a matrix of m x n dimensions. Here is what I've written:

```
[m,n] = size(A)
     for n=1:m
          P1 = max(A(:,n))
      end
```

I've tested this with a random 3x3 matrix in my command window and it prints out:

```
P1 = max of whatever is in column 1
P1 = max of whatever is in column 2
P1 = max of whatever is in column 3
```

However, it only stores: "P1 = max of whatever is in column 3"
I am assuming this is because the for loop runs it through three times since m = 3 so it stores the ending value.

What I want is:

```
P1 = max of whatever is in column 1
P2 = max of whatever is in column 2
P3 = max of whatever is in column 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MATLAB function [genvarname](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/genvarname.html) does what you want. In your case it would look something like:

```
[m,n] = size(A)
    for n=1:m
        eval(genvarname(sprintf('P%d', n), who)) = max(A(:,n))
    end
```

After the program completes, use the who function to view the workspace variables:

```
who

n m P1 P2 P3
```

But please note that `genvarname will be removed in a future release`.

LE: As sugested in the comments, using dynamic field references would be a more supported, efficient and readable approach.

```
[m,n] = size(A)
    for n=1:m
        index = sprintf('%d', n);
        P.{index} = max(A(:,n))
    end
```